# Error while use custom class when implement IProfileService. The type 'IProfileService' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: identityserver4

I'm updating IdentityServer from 2.2 to 2.4. I have two projects one its entry point and another for services. 
I updated both projects to 2.4 and facing an issue with:

> The type 'IProfileService' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced.

Also, I have another error:

> The type 'ClaimsProfileService' cannot be used as type parameter 'T'
>   in the generic type or method
>   'IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsAdditional.AddProfileService(IIdentityServerBuilder)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ClaimsProfileService'
>   to 'IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService'.

The class ClaimsProfileService implemented the interface IProfileService.  It looks weird, 'cause when I downgrade IdentityServer to 2.2 it's work properly.

Actually, there present strange behavior, when I created a nested class in my Startup.cs than implemented IProfileService I got no errors.

This is my identity server confiration.

```cs
var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                    options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7200);
                })
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources, CORS)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    // options.TokenCleanupInterval = 15; // interval in seconds. 15 seconds useful for debugging
                })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddProfileService<ClaimsProfileService>()
                .AddExtensionGrantValidator<DelegationGrantValidator>();
```

This is PackageReferences for main app project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery.Validation" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" Version="3.2.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is PackageReferences for Services project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Thank for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed. Just deleted from NuGet folder version 2.2 manually. Then I reinstalled IdentityServer and all work properly.